# numpy ndarrays: Is it possible to access a row based on a member element?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 2x3 ndarray:

```
[[0,1,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

I want to replace {any row that has 0 in the first index} with `[0,0,0]`:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [1,1,1]]
```

Is it possible to do this with np.where?
Here's my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0,1,1],[1,1,1]])
replacement = np.full(arr.shape,[0,0,0])
new = np.where(arr[:,0]==0,replacement,arr)
```

I'm met with the following error at the last line:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3) (2,3)
```

The error makes sense, but I don't know how to fix the code to accomplish my goal. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
I was trying to simplify a higher-dimensional case, but turns out it might not generalize.

If I have this ndarray:

```
[[[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
 [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
 [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]
```

how can I replace the first triplet with `[0,0,0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple indexing/broadcasting will do:

```
a[a[:,0]==0] = [0,0,0]
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

explanation:

```
# get first column
a[:,0]
# array([0, 1])

# compare to 0 creating a boolean array
a[:,0]==0
# array([ True, False])

# select rows where the boolean is True
a[a[:,0]==0]
# array([[0, 1, 1]])

# replace those rows with new array
a[a[:,0]==0] = [0,0,0]
```

###### using `np.where`

this is less elegant in my opinion:

```
a[np.where(a[:,0]==0)[0]] = [0,0,0]
```

##### Edit: generalization

input:

```
a = np.arange(3**3).reshape((3,3,3))

array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

transformation:

```
a[a[...,0]==0] = [0,0,0]

array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Unfortunately, I think I phrased the problem in a way that doesn't generalize to my specific case. How would this work if I wanted to replace axis=2 lists based on an element?

Comment: @kournex can you update your question with examples?

Comment: I just updated, let me know if it's unclear at all :)

Comment: @kournex check the update, this is the exact same logic, with indexing the last dimension ;)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for your help! (who knew python has ellipses!?)